# C# Databinding does not contain property with name

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am creating a ListBoxFor with a MultiSelectList, but I get the following error: `DataBinding: *.Models.Facilities does not contain a property with the name FacilitiesList.`

Here's my view:

```
@model *.Models.Reservation

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FacilitiesList, "Facilities", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.FacilitiesList, ViewBag.FacilitiesList as MultiSelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

The viewbag FacilitiesList is populated as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.FacilitiesList = new SelectList(_facilityrepository.GetAll(), "FacilitiesList", "FacilityType");
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Simple solution:

I changed this:

```
ViewBag.FacilitiesList = new SelectList(_facilityrepository.GetAll(), "FacilitiesList", "FacilityType");
```

to this:

```
ViewBag.FacilitiesList = new SelectList(_facilityrepository.GetAll(), "FacilityId", "FacilityType");
```